# GitLab CD workflow to deploy Docker app into staging and production

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've recently set up GitLab (13.4.3-ee) CI/CD to build and deploy a Docker
container into production.  This works great but I'd like to add a staging
step and despite reading a bunch, I can't seem to figure out a workable
way of doing this.

I think one of the problems I have is that following tutorials, I depend on a
docker-compose file to deploy into production.

If I added a step to deploy to a different (staging) runner then the `image:`
statement that I use in production is not useful as it installs the `latest`
image.  I didn't really want to use the `latest` tag on the docker image unless I was
about to deploy that image into production.

I considered replacing the docker-compose command in the deploy stage to a
series of manual steps to reproduce the compose file, but this seems messy,
especially when the app depends on other containers.

Any suggestions on how I should approach this?

### .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

# Build and tag :master and :latest images if on master branch
build-master:
  # Official docker image.
  image: docker:19.03.12-dind
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:19.03.12-dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    - docker build --pull -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  # Only run this job on the master branch.
  only:
    - master

build-test:
  # Official docker image.
  image: docker:19.03.12-dind
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:19.03.12-dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    - docker build --pull -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  # Do not run job on master branch
  except:
    - master

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  # Specify runner
  tags:
    - prod
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    # In production, pull the latest image.
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    - docker-compose down
    - docker-compose up -d
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

### docker-compose.yml

Note that this is a much cut down version of the actual docker-compose file.

```yaml
---
version: '3'

services:
    buildit:
        image: my-gitlab-registry.local:5050/app/docker-build-test:latest
        container_name: docker-build-test
        ports:
            - 500:80
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use the `latest` tag at all.  Create a unique version tag per build, and inject that (maybe via an environment variable) into the `docker-compose.yml` file.  This avoids issues where the system thinks it's up-to-date because it's running some "latest" build, even if it's yesterday's "latest".

Answer (score 0):

You can use an environment variable to select you image tag. In your docker-compose you can do like this

```
---
version: '3'

services:
    buildit:
        image: my-gitlab-registry.local:5050/app/docker-build-test:${IMAGE_TAG:-latest} #latest is a default value
        container_name: docker-build-test
        ports:
            - 500:80
```

and in gitlab-ci

- during `build_master` you can push many tags
- during `deploy_prod` you can set IMAGE_TAG=master
- during `deploy_staging` you can set IMAGE_TAG=staging

```
....
build-master:
  # Official docker image.
  image: docker:19.03.12-dind
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:19.03.12-dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    - docker build --pull -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:master    # tag master
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:staging   # tag staging

  # Only run this job on the master branch.
  only:
    - master

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  # Specify runner
  tags:
    - prod
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    # In production, pull the latest image.
    - export IMAGE_TAG=master  
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    - docker-compose down
    - docker-compose up -d
  when: manual
  only:
    - master

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  # Specify runner
  tags:
    - prod
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    # In production, pull the latest image.
    - export IMAGE_TAG=staging  
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    - docker-compose down
    - docker-compose up -d
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

in this way you can avoid to pull the `latest` image, and you can pull the latest image on a specific tag

Comment: Thanks, that gives me something to think about.  Although I'm not sure if you meant to use the `environment` keyword if you intended to set an environment variable as that seems to be something different (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/)

I think the syntax for that is below, although the environment keyword does seem to be appropriate for what I'm trying to do, I can't really think how to apply it in my case.
```yaml
  variables:
    IMAGE_TAG: staging
```

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake. `environvent` is not valid in gitlab-ci. Anyway you can use the same approch by setting the environment variable in the script